# ¿Cómo Incluir una Variable de JavaScript en Jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jqgrid

Estoy tratando de pasarle variables al jqgrid por javascript a través de un ajax este es mi código:

```
        type:  'POST', //método de envio   

            url:   'recorre_campos.php', //archivo que recibe la peticion
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            dataType: "json",



            success:  function (d) { 

                    alert(d[0]["DES_HAB"]);
                    alert(d[1]["DES_HAB"]);
                    var des_hab_1=d[0]["DES_HAB"];
                    var des_hab_2=d[1]["DES_HAB"];
                    alert(des_hab_1);
                    alert(des_hab_2);



            }
    });

  $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
    url: 'consulta_traspuesta_haberes_total.php',
    datatype: "json",

     colNames:[
     des_hab_1,des_hab_2 //las variables que no funcionan
     ],
     colModel: [

     { label:des_hab_1, name:des_hab_1},
     {label:des_hab_2,name:des_hab_2}

     ]
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO Daniel, te recomiendo leer [Como Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y podamos ayudarte mas rápidamente. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontre la solucion, jqgrid no puedo poner variables, solo valores fijos en el atributo colnames por lo tanto lo hice por php construyendo mi tabla con las columnas variables :

```
    $nombres1 = implode("=>", $campos[0]);
    $nombres2 = implode("=>", $campos[1]);
    $nombres3 = implode("=>", $campos[2]);
    $nombres4 = implode("=>", $campos[3]);
    $nombres5 = implode("=>", $campos[4]);
    $nombres6 = implode("=>", $campos[5]);
    $nombres7 = implode("=>", $campos[6]);
    $nombres8 = implode("=>", $campos[7]);
    $nombres9 = implode("=>", $campos[8]);
    $nombres10 = implode("=>", $campos[9]);
    $parametro1=$nombres1;
    $parametro2=$nombres2;
    $parametro3=$nombres3;
    $parametro4=$nombres4;
    $parametro5=$nombres5;
    $parametro6=$nombres6;
    $parametro7=$nombres7;
    $parametro8=$nombres8;
    $parametro9=$nombres9;
    $parametro10=$nombres10;
    $sql = "SELECT APELLIDOS,NOMBRES,RUT,MES,SUM($parametro1) as $parametro1,SUM($parametro2) as $parametro2,SUM($parametro3) as $parametro3,
            SUM($parametro4) as $parametro4,SUM($parametro5) as $parametro5,SUM($parametro6) as $parametro6,SUM($parametro7) as $parametro7,SUM($parametro8) as $parametro8,SUM($parametro9) as $parametro9,SUM($parametro10) as $parametro10,SUM($parametro1) + SUM($parametro2) + SUM($parametro3) + SUM($parametro4) + SUM($parametro5) + SUM($parametro6) +  SUM($parametro7) + SUM($parametro8) + SUM($parametro9) + SUM($parametro10)
            as TOTAL  from base_haberes where $parametro1<>0 or $parametro2<>0 group by RUT,MES ORDER BY MES ASC";
    mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); 
    //echo $sql;
    if(!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) die();
    //echo $sql;
    echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-hover' id='contenido' name='contenido'>";  
    echo "<tr>";  



    echo "<th>APELLIDOS</th>";  
            echo "<th>NOMBRES</th>";  
            echo "<th>RUT</th>";    
            echo "<th>MES</th>";                
            echo "<th>".$parametro1."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$parametro2."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$parametro3."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$parametro4."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$parametro5."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$parametro6."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$parametro7."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$parametro8."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$parametro9."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$parametro10."</th>";
            echo "<th>TOTAL</th>";  
            echo "</tr>";


            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    { 
        $campo_c_apellidos = $row['APELLIDOS'];
            $campo_c_nombres = $row['NOMBRES'];
            $rut_c = $row['RUT'];
            $mes_c = $row['MES'];
            $nombre1 = $row[$parametro1];
            $nombre2 = $row[$parametro2];
            $nombre3 = $row[$parametro3];
            $nombre4 = $row[$parametro4];
            $nombre5 = $row[$parametro5];
            $nombre6 = $row[$parametro6];
            $nombre7 = $row[$parametro7];
            $nombre8 = $row[$parametro8];
            $nombre9 = $row[$parametro9];
            $nombre10 = $row[$parametro10];
            $total_pie = $row['TOTAL'];
            //echo $nombre1;
            $valores[] = array("APELLIDOS"=>$campo_c_apellidos,"NOMBRES"=>$campo_c_nombres,"RUT"=>$rut_C,"MES"=>$mes_c,"$parametro1"=>$nombre1,
            "$parametro2"=>$nombre2,"$parametro3"=>$nombre3,"$parametro4"=>$nombre4,"$parametro5"=>$nombre5,"$parametro6"=>$nombre6,"$parametro7"=>$nombre7,"$parametro8"=>$nombre8,"$parametro9"=>$nombre9,"$parametro10"=>$nombre10,"TOTAL"=>$total);


                echo "<tr>"; 
                echo "<td>".$campo_c_apellidos."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$campo_c_nombres."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$rut_c."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$mes_c."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$nombre1."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$nombre2."</td>";  
                echo "<td>".$nombre3."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$nombre4."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$nombre5."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$nombre6."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$nombre7."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$nombre8."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$nombre9."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$nombre10."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$total."</td>";                     

                echo "</tr>"; 


    }     

    echo "</table>"; 

    $json_string = json_encode($valores);
```

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que inicializar el `$("#jqGrid").jqGrid()` dentro del `success` del ajax. Dado que ajax es una llamada asincrona, cuando instancias el jqGrid, todavía no has recibido el valor de las variables `des_hab_1` y `des_hab_2`.

```
          success:  function (d) { 

                alert(d[0]["DES_HAB"]);
                alert(d[1]["DES_HAB"]);
                var des_hab_1=d[0]["DES_HAB"];
                var des_hab_2=d[1]["DES_HAB"];
                alert(des_hab_1);
                alert(des_hab_2);

                $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                   url: 'consulta_traspuesta_haberes_total.php',
                   datatype: "json",

                    colNames:[
                        des_hab_1,des_hab_2 //las variables que no funcionan
                    ],
                }

            ....................
});
```

Comment: No funca... debe dar problemas el parametro url o algo por el estilo, estoy viendo la documentacion de jqgrid parece que el atributo colname no puede cambiar o ser variable, de todos modos gracias igual espero mas opiniones o otra solucion.

Comment: Cuando dice que no se puede cambiar, se refiere a que una vez inicializado el jqGrid no puedes modificar ese valor, pero obviamente puedes pasar parametros a ese array al inicializarlo ¿Cual es el error que te muestra en la consola exactamente? ¿Los alert de las variables te muestran los valores que esperas?

Comment: los alerts me muestran exctamente lo que necesito, el problema que tengo es que no se como añadir los valores de las variables mas bien asignarle al nombre de la columna esos nombres. no me muestra error, simplemente vacio.

Comment: Podrías poner una imagen de como se te queda la tabla tras la llamada al jqGrid?

Comment: no se muestra el jqgrid, es como si tuviera un error y cuando coloco las cremillas los atributos del colnames me sale sin ningun problema pero estoy haciendolo con una tabla normal, haber si me resulta lo que necesito.

Comment: Amigo gracias, ley la documentacion completa de jqgrid, el atributo colnames no puede cambiar, por lo tanto tiene que ser un valor fijo, asi que lo hice por php y construi una tabla normal hice un nido de if con respectivas querys para construir la traspeusta que necesitaba Gracias de Todas maneras